# getting really annoying error: "Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in..."

Tags: php, arrays, string

How do i get rid of this error?

code:

```
        function get_green_entities($c,$array){
            $thisC = &$this->output[$this->sessID];    
            $timeDif = 4;
            $cols = count($thisC['clientCols'])+1;
            if(!isset($array['Entity ID'])){
                return get_grey($c);
            }
            if(!isset($thisC['CURRTIME'][$array['Entity ID']])){
                $thisC['CURRTIME'][$array['Entity ID']] = 
                      (isset($array['timestamp'])?$array['timestamp']:null);
            }
        }
```

I am hitting that error in that last if statement's line:

```
$thisC['CURRTIME'][$array['Entity ID']] = 
                          (isset($array['timestamp'])?$array['timestamp']:null);
```

And i know that `$array['Entity ID']=4`

How do i fix this?

Thanks :-)

**UPDATE 3** 

 I removed the dumps as they are a bit sensitive

Comment: Can you give us a var_dump of $thisC?

Comment: Which specific line(s) of code are you getting the offset error on, please?

Comment: i say above which line im getting the error. that did not change

Comment: what is the value of $array['Entity ID']

Comment: the value of `$array['Entity ID']` is 4

Comment: Can you give us a `var_dump` of `$array`?

Comment: not sure why the downvote. care to explain anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only three possibilities either `$thisC`, `$thisC['CURRTIME']`, or `$array` is not an array...

You can alter the function signature to protect against the latter:

```
function get_green_entities($c, array $array)
```

If `$array` is the problem, it will get triggered when calling the function. So now if the problem persists, you know it has something to do with `$thisC`.

Calling `var_dump` on the line before the error should make it obvious what the problem is.

Consider the behavior of:

```
$array = 'test';

if (!isset($array['foo']['bar']))
  $array['foo']['bar'] = true; // error is triggered here
```

So I would think the problem is that `$thisC['CURRTIME']` is not always an array like you expect.

Comment: @Neal, you say that it is "last successful." I took that to mean the one before the error is caused, which doesn't really offer an explanation. See my appended example in my answer for behavior that looks similar to what you are describing.

Comment: yes. i put the dump in the if statement. before the var was set

Comment: @Neal, you would only get that error message when setting multiple components of a string variable like `$a[0][1] = 'bar'`, due to PHP's odd type juggling, so given the code you've provided it has to be `$thisC` is not an array. You may want to try `if (!is_array($thisC)) die('...');` to check against that. You could also try replacing the reference with a copy/paste of the original to make sure something odd isn't happening with that.

Comment: than how when i `print_r($thisC)` i get an array result?

Comment: Note that `print_r(NULL)` (or '') displays nothing.

Comment: what does `NULL` have to do with anything?

Comment: If `$thisC` is `NULL` or `''` you wouldn't see anything in the output. Thus, you would see the previous dump and be debugging the wrong array. Try using `var_dump()`, as it will always output something.

Comment: for some reason at that point `$thisC` is a string: `string(19) "2011-03-21 15:11:05"`   how does that happen when i always refer to it as an array?

Comment: i found the error. thanks so much. later on in the code i was setting $thisC = string :-p